# Make 1 component editable in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a carousel slideshow on my *posts* index page which is hard coded but ideally id like it to be dynamic/editable in activeadmin, is there a simple way to do this so that potentially I could use this slideshow on a home page and not on the index view of *posts*.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a slides resource (ie, a slides table, model, views, etc). You could then set 'slides' to be editable through active admin, in the same way that Posts are editable.

You'd obviously want one of the fields in your slides table to be an image upload - so you can use a gem like [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle that.

Then, where you currently build your carousel with hard-coded references to images, just build it based on the data stored in your slides table. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `image` model, with a `url` attribute. On any page, you just loop through these images and print the `url` where the carousel load the images.